# FFMPEG output as Mp4 video for mov input video

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

Can i generate output as mp4 video for the following ffmpeg code ?

```
echo exec('ffmpeg -vcodec qtrle -i z.mov -vcodec qtrle -i Gillette_Alpha_Sample2.mov -filter_complex "[0:0][1:0]overlay=format=rgb[out]" -shortest -map [out] -vcodec qtrle -y output.mov');
```

Comment: That `qtrle` doesn't look right. MPEG's MP4 container accepts only MPEG's own a/v codecs.. For video use either H.264 or H.265, and then for audio use either AAC or MP3. Try `ffmpeg -i Gillette_Alpha_Sample2.mov -i z.mov output.mp4` as a test. FFmpeg will intelligently encode from MOV into correct MPEG codecs for you. Later you can try adding multiple inputs etc. To avoid errors make sure that both MOV are **same display size (w & h) and framerate**

Comment: Can i overlap z.mov video over Gillette_Alpha_Sample2.mov and take mp4 out by using the code you gave ?

z.mov is a transparent video with alpha channel.

Comment: Its fixed. `echo exec('ffmpeg -i z.mov -i Gillette_Alpha_Sample2.mov -filter_complex "[0:0][1:0]overlay=format=rgb[out]" -b:v 768k -shortest -map [out] output.mp4');`

But i wonder why the frame width and height shows as 16 and 160 ? how i can change it ?

Comment: Fixed `echo exec('ffmpeg -i z.mov -i Gillette_Alpha_Sample2.mov -filter_complex "[0:0][1:0]overlay[out]" -s 480x640 -b:v 768k -b:a 64k -map [out] -y output.mp4');`

Comment: If you want to overlay `z` over `gillette` then the order of the inputs should be reversed.

Comment: @TittuVaghese, you should post the solution in the answer box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
exec('ffmpeg -i z.mov -i Gillette_Alpha_Sample2.mov -filter_complex "[0:0][1:0]overlay[out]" -s 480x640 -b:v 768k -b:a 64k -map [out] -y output.mp4');
```

This will output mp4 video for mov inputs.

Answer (score 0):

No. QT RLE isn't supported in MP4 container, not by FFmpeg muxer at least. You will have to use `libx264rgb` if you want to keep RGB, or `libx264` if you are OK with YUV pixel formats.